# pandas replace string value if not in a list

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
     city
0 los angeles
1 houston
2 new york
:
:
100 boston
:
:
```

How can I replace all the city names to *other* which are not in in the following list?

```
los angeles
saint petersburg
honolulu
Denverver
las vegas
saint louis
phoenix
houston
atlanta
philadelphia
orlando
chicago
san francisco
kailua kona
```

Comment: `df.loc[~df['city'].isin(your_list), 'city'] = 'other'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
cities = ['los angeles',
 'saint petersburg',
 'honolulu',
 'Denverver',
 'las vegas',
 'saint louis',
 'phoenix',
 'houston',
 'atlanta',
 'philadelphia',
 'orlando',
 'chicago',
 'san francisco',
 'kailua kona']

df.loc[~df["city"].isin(cities), "city"] = "other"
```